# Поиск дубликатов в большом массиве

Tags: алгоритм

Некоторое время назад мне дали шуточную задачку:

Имеется массив 1000000*1000000 записей, в каждой ячейке целое число. Требуется вывести все не дублирующиеся элементы.

**Важно** выполнить КАК МОЖНО меньше операций, т.е. нельзя сортировать.

У меня было много разных идей, но все они сводились к сортировке. В общем, без сортировки я не справился, грубо говоря.

Есть у  Вас какие-то идеи, как это можно сделать?

Comment: > Есть у Вас какие-то идеи

А у вас? Эт я к тому, что на форуме не принято решать учебные задачи за учащихся.

Comment: @Deonis что вы прикапываетесь-то к этим учебным задачам. Может, друг дал. Вряд ли преподаватель будет задавать "шуточную задачку".
Но соглашусь, что было бы полезно приводить попытки своих размышлений и где конкретно человек не смог продвинуться дальше.

Comment: @Leonard Bertone, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы определить, выводить ли текущий элемент, необходимо знать выводили ли мы уже этот элемент раньше. Для этого нужно просмотреть все выведенные раньше элементы. Основная задача - ускорить процесс просмотра. Наиболее эффективный способ этого добиться - хранить выведенные элементы не в обычном массиве, а в какой-нибудь структуре данных, в которой поиск осуществляется за время, меншее O(N). Это может быть [бинарное дерево поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) и его разновидности ([AVL-tree](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), [B-tree](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), [RB-tree](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)), [хэш-таблицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), [списки с пропусками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8). Такие структуры позволяют ускорить поиск вхождения до O(NlogN). Также может помочь такая структура как [фильтр Блума](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: в моем решении лучше - там проверка - это O(1). Вряд ли Вы придумаете лучше.

Comment: В условии не сказано, что значения - числа. В случае строк ваш алгоритм бесполезен.

Comment: Ну как бы вообще то сказано

> записей, в каждом целое число.

Comment: Прошу прощения, после слова "записей" перестал читать. Тогда ваш алгоритм действительно наилучший.

Comment: @fori1ton, а про хэширование (хэш-код) что-нибудь слышали? (Это я про строки).

Answer (score 9):

Даже если каждое число по 4 байта, то это

```
1000000 * 1000000 * 4 / 1024/1024/1024/1024 = 3.7 Терабайта.
```

В оперативку уж точно не вместиться.

Итак, если там однобайтовые числа. Заводим массив на 256 элементов, проходимся последовательно по оригинальному массиву. Используя число как индекс смотрим в первом массиве значение. Если там 0, записываем 1, если единица - пишем 2, если 2 - не трогаем.
По окончанию просмотра большого массива смотрим в маленький. Там, где значения нулевые, этих элементов нет, где 1 - для них нет дубликатов. Где двойки - там есть дубликаты. Сложность алгоритма - O(n).

Если числа двухбайтовые, то тут суть та же, 64к массив - это не так много.

Если числа 4-байтовые, то тут придется немного помучаться, так как заводить массив на 4 гигабайта (на каждое число по байту) как-то накладно, можно паковать по 4 числа в байт (на кодирования наличия элемента нужно всего два бита). Это "всего" 1 гигабайт (если нашлось место для 4 терабайт данных, то один гиг найдется). Если памяти мало, то можно попробовать паковать блоки, то есть хранить не одним массивом, а разбить на блоки, к примеру, по 1024 элемента. Если в блоке хранятся одинаковые числа, то можно просто хранить это значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Задача идет без привязки к какому-либо языку программирования. Мне намекнули, что оно задача решается как-то элементарно( вот только как, мне не известно, пока что. Но спасибо за участие!

Comment: возможно, задача звучала так "все элементы имеют дубликат, кроме одного элемента. тройных повторений нет". Тогда это просто классическая задача с xor. Другое дело, что четное кол-во элементов массива не способствует этому.

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решить за O(n) времени и O(1) памяти с использованием [BitVector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) если допустить, что массив соджержит только положительные числа.

Пример на Java:

```
class Main {
    static int getBitVectorOfUnique(int[] arr) {
        int bitVector = 0;
        int bitVectorOfNonUnique = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            int mask = 1 << arr[i];
            if ((bitVector & mask) == 0) {
                bitVector |= mask;
            } else if((bitVectorOfNonUnique & mask) == 0) {
                bitVectorOfNonUnique |= mask;
            }
        }
        return (bitVector ^ bitVectorOfNonUnique);
    }
    static void printUniq(int[] arr) {
        int bitVector = getBitVectorOfUnique(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            int mask = 1 << arr[i];
            if ((bitVector & mask) != 0) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 5, 1, 10, 12, 10, 2147483646, 2147483647, 2147483647};
        printUniq(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: O(1) в памяти очевидно невозможно с O(n) по времени как количество уникальных целых так и дубликатов может зависеть от n.

Answer (score -3):

1) Берём крайний от начала массива элемент и ищем дубликат начиная со следующего и до конца массива. 
2) Если дубликат не найден - выводим текущий элемент.
3) Делаем крайним элементом следующий и повторяем п.1